# Qt 5.5.1: Cannot find -lGL

Tags: opengl, qt-creator, mesa, qt5.5, qtopengl

I have developed an GUI application on `Qt 5.3.1`. I am using Qt Creator `3.1.2 (based on Qt 5.3.1)` to build my GUI application and am able to build and deploy my application successfully.

I wanted to update my qt creator and for that I have installed the latest `Qt Creator 3.5.1 (based on Qt 5.5.1)` and provided necessary changes to build my existing QT GUI application on this latest qt creator. Everything went well and just about to create the final executable, the build was terminated with below error information:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test-app (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 GCC 32bit)
```

I tried to search online and found this suggestion to update the Mesa package!. *[If that is the case, why is that the same application was building fine on my Qt creator 3.1.2. I want to know some details before trying the fix to update mesa package.]*

Can somebody provide me some pointers to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
When I built my GUI application on Qt 5.3.1 the below libraries are linked to my final executable:

```
-lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lGAL
```

The same application when I built on Qt 5.5.1 version the below libraries are linked to my final executable:

```
-lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core -lGL
```

I had to update mesa package as suggested by @Kyrylo Polezhaiev to resolve the issue with -lGL

**I am missing a piece here: 
Was it that the OpenGL packages `-lGLESv2 -lEGL -lGAL` from older qt version (5.3.1) is just equivalent to `-lGL` on latest qt creator 5.5.1 version ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means linker couldn't find library named libGL.
Do you have Mesa's devel files (headers and libs)? Where?
You can specify additional library path with -L option.
Can you compare linker invocation commands?

About second part: OpenGL ES is a subset of the OpenGL for embedded systems like smartphones ("compact" version of OpenGL). It means you switched your app to "adult" version of OpenGL. Mesa is open-source implementation of OpenGL. Those libs are part of Mesa.